# How can I add my own solution to Google Cloud Launcher Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

We created an application which might be useful for any developer.

We like to create a deployment in Google Cloud Launcher so any Google Cloud users can make use of application via Google Cloud Launcher.

I don't find in-depth documentation to create a solution in Google Cloud Launcher. Also I don't find the steps required to push our application into Google Cloud Launcher.

Basically we would like to do something like bitnami does. 
What are the steps required to package our application as Google Cloud Launcher solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To offer a Launcher, you can contact the Partner Program here https://cloud-partners-program.appspot.com/registration/technology